# Logic - finding most general statement

Tags: logic

Let A and B be sets. For each statement below, please write down the most general statements you can make about A and B. Make sure you justify your answer.

a. A ∪ B = A?

b. A ∩ B = A?

c. A ∪ B = A ∩ B?

d. A − B = A?

e. A − B = B − A?

Please Correct me,

a.B= $\varnothing$ or B$\subseteq$ A

b. B= U

c. A=B

d. A ∩ B = $\varnothing$

e. A=B

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- a. $A \cup B = A.\quad$ 
  Here, your conclusion that $B\subseteq A$ suffices. 
  Since the empty set is a subset of every set, so even if it is the case that $B = \varnothing$, that is covered by "$B\subseteq A$".
- b. $A \cap B = A$
  From (b) you can conclude $\;A\subseteq B$. 
  (It's not necessarily the case that $B = U$, where $U$ is the universal set; you can, however, write $A \subseteq B \subseteq U$.)
- c. $\to$ e. These look good to me!

---

Comment: Your welcome, Hoorman. Do you see why (b) means $A\subseteq B$?

Comment: Sure , U = Universe ,Thanks for the help